# yii2 без определенных аттрибутов

Tags: php, yii2

Как вернуть модель без некоторых аттрибутов, таких как password и auth_token

Answer (score 1):

Через построитель запросов явно указать какие поля вам нужны. Где-то так:

```
User::find()->select(['id', 'name', 'other_fields'])->one();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете "спрятать" нужные поля в методе модели afterFind()
Или же использовать конструктор запросов с явным указанием необходимых возвращаемых полей таблицы